# Sort by lexicographical_compare() function

Tags: c++, sorting

Is there any way to sort a string using the `lexicographical_compare()` function in C++?

I can do it by STL sort, but my question is about the `lexicographical_compare()` function.

Comment: The strings in c++ are lexicographically compared by default. Please give more information on **what exactly** you want to do. You may also give some example input and output.

Comment: suppose  i have some string "apple" , "Apple" ,"AppLe" , "APPLe" ........... Now i want to sort them lexicographically.

Comment: Sort already sorts lexicographically.

Comment: @StuartJecoroxy so what you actually need is to ignore case. Simply write a custom predicate for that.

Comment: std::sort() does not do lexigraphic ordering it does comparison of each char underlying binary. So it is effected by the encoding scheme. A lexigraphic order should adhere to linguistic standards and not be effected by the binary encoding scheme. So the output of std::sort on utf8/ascii will be ` % 5 ? A B C D ] a b c d }` but a lexigraphic sort should yield something more like `% ] } ? 5 A a B b C c D d` or `5 a A b B c C d D ? % ] }`

Answer (score 7):

The question is poorly worded. Of course, `std::lexicographical_compare` doesn't modify anything, so to sort you can't just use `std::lexicographical_compare`: you have to use `std::sort` (or equivalent) somehow. The correct answer to "how do you lexicographically sort a container of `std::string`s is `std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end())` because `operator<` on `std::string`s is a lexicographical comparison.

On the assumption that your question is an example of a broader question of how do you sort range of containers into lexicographic order (which is really more of a question of how do you use custom comparison function objects to alter the behavior of `std::sort`), you just provide `std::sort` with a comparison operator. For example:

```
// A function objecto to do lexicographical comparisons
template <typename Container>
bool LexCompare(const Container& a, const Container& b) {
    return std::lexicographical_compare(a.begin(), a.end(),
                                        b.begin(), b.end());
}

// Use that comparison function to sort a range:
template <typename ContainerIterator>
void sort_by_lexicographical_comapre(ContainerIterator beg,
                                     ContainerIterator end)
{
    std::sort(beg, end, LexCompare<typename ContainerIterator::value_type>);
}


int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    v.push_back(std::string());
    v[0].push_back('1');
    v[0].push_back('3');
    v[0].push_back('0');
    v.push_back(std::string());
    v[1].push_back('1');
    v[1].push_back('3');
    sort_by_lexicographical_comapre(v.begin(), v.end());

    for (int i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << v[i] << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can change the above to have `v` have type `std::vector<std::vector<int> >` and push back integers into them and it will still work.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need `std::lexicographical_compare` to sort a string. You just need the `std::sort` algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  std::string s("qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm");
  std::cout << s << "\n";
  std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());
  std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

The same applies to sorting a collection of strings:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> v{"apple" , "Apple" ,"AppLe" , "APPLe"};
  for (const auto& s : v)
    std::cout << s << " ";
  std::cout << "\n";
  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
  for (const auto& s : v)
    std::cout << s << " ";
  std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I have already tell that i can do it by STL sort But i thought if here is any way to sort it by **lexicographical_compare()** function.

Comment: @StuartJecoroxy why would you want to do that? The sort is already done lexicographically.